Prevent Excel from crashing when creating multiple pdf's
I have a large Excel sheet where I use vba code via a simple do loop to generate a number of pdfs from a given worksheet. The sheet is used for invoicing and the worksheet where the invoice amounts are calculated contains quite a number of formulas.
The code I use to generate a pdf is the following:
Function saveRangeAsPDF(rangeName As String, showMsg As Boolean)
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim Folderstring As String
    Dim FilePathName As String
    Dim ccRng As Range
    Dim sMsg As String

    ' If my ActiveSheet is landscape, I must attach this line
    ' for making the PDF also landscape, seems to default to xlPortait
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation

    ' Ensure the filename does not contain invalid characters
    FileName = Trim(Cells(9, 2).Value) & "_" & Cells(6, 2).Value & "_" & Cells(2, 9).Value & "_" & Cells(2, 2).Value & "_" & Cells(2, 16).Value
    FileName = Replace(FileName, ":", "_")
    FileName = Replace(FileName, "/", "_")
    FileName = Replace(FileName, "\", "_")
    FileName = Replace(FileName, "*", "_")
    FileName = Replace(FileName, "?", "_")
    FileName = Replace(FileName, Chr(34), "_") ' Replaces " with _
    FileName = Replace(FileName, "<", "_")
    FileName = Replace(FileName, ">", "_")
    FileName = Replace(FileName, "|", "_")

    sMsg = Cells(9, 2).Value & " - " & Cells(2, 2).Value

    Set ccRng = ActiveSheet.Range(rangeName)
    If CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(ccRng.Row + ccRng.Rows.Count, 2)) = "CC" Then
        FileName = FileName & "_" & CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(ccRng.Row + ccRng.Rows.Count, 3))
    End If

    FileName = FileName & ".pdf"

    Folderstring = getSaveFolder()
    If Folderstring = "" Then
        MsgBox "Geen geldige map geselecteerd.", vbExclamation
        Exit Function
    End If

    FilePathName = Folderstring & Application.PathSeparator & FileName

    setPrintSettings (rangeName)
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    ActiveSheet.Range(rangeName).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=FilePathName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    If showMsg Then
         Call AddStatus("Factuurbestand (PDF) aangemaakt, deze bevind zich in de volgende locatie : " & FilePathName)
    End If

    Exit Function

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Er is een fout opgetreden bij het genereren van de PDF: " & Err.Description, vbCritical

End Function

I can't figure out what caused the crash now, but what is certain is that the cause is the pdf generation. Is there anyone who has experience with this or knows a better method of generating a pdf other than the ExportAsFixedFormat method?
The calculation is always set to manual and all calculation is done by VBA, by Application. CalculateFull method. When I create the pdf's manually each one at a time, s not by the loop, the file sometimes crashes as well. When I open the file again and run the macro again everything is fine. The file is about 45Mb and my IMac has 32 GB internal memory to spent. I monitor the use of memory but most of the time not even half of the memory is actually used. The filename is checked for invalid characters which are replaced at once.

Could you share the complete code?

I shared the code as you asked. Do you have a clue? Does anybody?
